# Excel The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have created a code that will save the Excel file in CSV format and email it using GMail as an attachment.

However, I am getting a run-time error which says The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Please see part of the code below where I am getting the error. Would like to know how to resolve this.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
'set the current directory to the location of the template
ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
myDir = ThisWorkbook.Path

'capture username
userName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Range("D2").Value
gMail = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("B1").Value
sPassword = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("B3").Value
'capture date
yDate = Format(Now, "mmddyy")

'save workbook as csv file
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").SaveAs Filename:= _
"report_" & userName & "_" & Format(Now, "mmddyy"), _
FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

'***********************************
'****send csv file as attachment****
'***********************************
Dim NewMail As Object
fName = "report_" & userName & "_" & yDate & ".csv"
myDir = myDir & "\"

Set NewMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = gMail

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = sPassword

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

'Set All Email Properties
With NewMail
  .Subject = "Report for " & userName & " " & yDate
  .From = gMail
  .To = "ddoctor@yahoo.com"
  .CC = ""
  .BCC = ""
  .AddAttachment myDir & Dir(myDir & fName) 'This is where I am getting the error
End With

NewMail.send

MsgBox ("Mail has been Sent")

'Set the NewMail Variable to Nothing
Set NewMail = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End If
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code?

Comment: if you using VBA code `open` to write out file, dont forget to close him too. Or else it will be blocked

Comment: I have edited my post. Please see the rest of the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most efficient way but it worked perfectly well. After saving the Excel Workbook as CSV, I saved it again as CSV with a different filename then attached the first CSV file.

```
'save workbook as csv file
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").SaveAs Filename:= _
"report_" & userName & "_" & Format(Now, "mmddyy"), _
FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

'save workbook as csv file with different filename
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").SaveAs Filename:= _
"report_" & userName & "_" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & "(copy)", _
FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

'***********************************
'****send csv file as attachment****
'***********************************
Dim NewMail As Object
fName = "report_" & userName & "_" & yDate & ".csv"
myDir = myDir & "\"

Set NewMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = gMail

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = sPassword

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

'Set All Email Properties
With NewMail
  .Subject = "Report for " & userName & " " & yDate
  .From = gMail
  .To = "ddoctor@yahoo.com"
  .CC = ""
  .BCC = ""
  .AddAttachment myDir & Dir(myDir & fName)
End With

NewMail.send

MsgBox ("Mail has been Sent")

'Set the NewMail Variable to Nothing
Set NewMail = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End If
```